# WCF much slower than WebAPI running same code

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I currently have 2 exposed endpoints. The first is WebAPI (.NET 4.6). The second is WCF (.NET 3.5). They are both capable of performing the same calculation, however the WCF is on average 10 times slower. The calculation code in question is contained in a dll, lets call it core.dll. This dll also exposes the WCF endpoints and is used by an ASP.NET site. The webapi dll, lets call it api.dll references core.dll and is used by an SPA. The calculation can be triggered by either client. On average, with my test data, the WCF service takes about 4.5 seconds to perform the calculation, where as the WebAPI takes about 450 milliseconds (or about 10 times faster).

I should note that all database calls are done outside of the measured time frame. All data is retrieved before hand and all updates are made after the calculation has completed.

All things being equal is there any reason I could be seeing this big of a difference in pure processing speed?

*I am 100% sure that the data is the same for both clients and they both receive the same result.*

```
WEBAPI Controller
    Service
        GRAB DATA
        start timer
        Process(DATA) -- the same code/class as below
        end timer
        UPDATE DATA
    Service return
WEBAPI Controller return

WCF Endpoint
    Service
        GRAB DATA
        start timer
        Process(DATA) -- the same code/class as above
        end timer
        UPDATE DATA
    Service return
WCF Endpoint return
```

EDIT: added diagram for clarity (hopefully)

EDIT 2: 
Thanks for the answers/comments. Unfortunately it doesn't look like anything conclusive will come of this question. My colleagues and I ultimately choose to believe that this just a pure difference in the efficiency of the Framework versions. We ended up restructuring the web service so that the calculation only happens in the WebAPI.

Comment: Well you could at least include ProcessData code and how you measure time, just for people to be sure you are not missing something. Also since you mentioned different .net versions I suppose they run on different machines?

Comment: The process code is too long, it's contained in about 20 files (probably close to 500 lines). They run on the same machine, the individual dll's are just build with different .NET versions. Time is measured using c# `StopWatch`, started and stopped before and after the call to `process(data)`

Comment: Well I cannot imagine what could cause such a difference then. Maybe they run in a processes with different priority?

Comment: What if you force your WCF application to run on later version of .NET using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5?

Comment: @Evk That's not an option for us, some modules in the WCF service cannot be upgraded past 3.5 without major refactoring/re-writing of the application due to dependencies on the old framework.

Comment: But I don't mean to recompile or rewrite anything. I mean using `supportedRuntime` attribute in app.config file as stated in my link above.

Comment: I added this to the web.config, it had no effect on the version. I also tried updating the version of the application pool to 4.0, however this results in 500 errors on any request. @Evk

Comment: Can you mock it to test the Process(DATA) with same runtime? E.g. create test service with two endpoints both having .Net 4.6, without GRAB DATA and UPDATE DATA phases, only Update(DATA) with DATA being hardcoded as a constant, to strip away all modules which cannot be upgraded to from .net 3.5 ?

Comment: Is it possible to change WCF .Net version to 4.6 and repeat the test? It can help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**Use a profiler**.

Get better data, out of process, without all the hastle.  Profile both for CPU usage and memory, GC collections, hot path, etc...

*That said...*

You're comparing two vastly different .NET versions.  That makes it impossible to do a fair benchmark.

.NET 4.6 introduced a new JIT for 64-bit that's significantly faster.  And that's just one difference.  Too many to list.

If you can't change the .NET version you will **never** get an accurate benchmark, but can look for suspects.  I would absolutely use a profiler, but if benchmarking:

Take a look at the generated `IL` (pre-JIT) and also ensure you benchmark post-JIT (IL -> machine code).

One easy way is to simply run both benchmarks once (not measured) as a "cold start" before you start the actual benchmark.

Another is to use `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` prior to the benchmark to JIT methods so you're not measuring JIT time.

Of course, ensure your benchmark is fair.

Plenty of information out there, but ensure you're using high resolution timers, use a large sample size (repeat many times),  Do a `GC.Collect()` before each measurement, use the same hardware (testing on the same box), etc...

Correctly doing benchmarks in-process (as opposed to profiling) is really *not*
as easy as it looks.

Anything else is just speculation on our part.  I couldn't really comment unless you posted real code that would reproduce your behavior.

Comment: @Evk that is not true. Even if he runs on the same machine. The machine can hold up different .NET Versions at a time. For example i have all the .net versions all the way from .net framework 2 to .net framework 4.7.1 and .net core 1 , .net core 1.1 and .net core 2. Each Project chooses the runtime that is configured to run not the latest.

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos well at least it's possible that they are run on the same .NET version (his 3.5 service may run on 4.6 version I mean), worth checking by the OP if they are or not. And if not - force 3.5 to run on later version and see if that helps with the problem

Comment: @Zer0 can you recommend a profiler? At this point (see my second edit) we have abandoned this effort, but I am still curious to find some result.

Comment: @CallbackKid I personally use a wide number depending on situation (all have pros and cons).  As a start I would recommend Red Gate's "ANTS" for performance and SciTech's ".NET Memory Profiler" for memory.  I probably also should mention it may be worthwhile to do packet capture and inspection.  Using something akin to Wireshark.  That gives you detailed network-level information.  I'm not a fan so YMMV, but Visual Studio has a built-in profiler.

Answer (score 3):

My call is that you see such a difference because from .net 3.5 to .net 4.6 there were big performance boosts. If you do heavy use of framework elements that could be the issue.

Check the links bellow (They contain information about performance boosts):

- [What's new in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/)
- [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility)
- [Performance Improves in .NET 4.6](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/07/Net-46-Performance)
- [C# Benchmark .NET 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5](https://www.dotnetperls.com/net-35-net-40-benchmark)
- [Top 10 New Improvements Found in the .NET Framework Version 4.6.2](https://blog.appdynamics.com/product/top-10-new-improvements-found-in-the-net-framework-version-4-6-2/)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a combination of a few things.  Namely the performance of REST (WebAPI) vs SOAP (WCF), especially depending on the amount of data being sent/received. As well as the fact that hosting a WCF service in ASP.NET, I don't think the service actually is running or initialized until it is called, so you'll have some initialization time.

Comment: The measured performance is not including network time. So I don't imaging it could be a REST/SOAP issue. As for initialization time, it's possible, but I only see this slow down in one instance, and not in other shared calls between the endpoints.

Comment: Gotcha.  To be honest I've seen some slowness on WCF vs WebAPI as well and was puzzled on it, maybe I can dig further into it.  IIRC all that has to happen for WebAPI is the ApiController being instantiated for the method call, which should be quicker than initialization of a WCF service.

Comment: So if I ran the calculation multiple times in one service call I should see the performance increase on subsequent calculations?

Comment: Yes, if the lack of performance was due to initialization, I'd say that would be what you'd see.

Comment: Although, looking at your diagram, I'm not sure that's the case.  It's still worth testing, though.

Comment: Ok, tested that, first round was 4.5 seconds, second round was 2.5 seconds. still > 5 times slower than WebAPI. Inconclusive but interesting

Comment: However I saw the same ratio of speed up when running multiple passes in the webapi

Answer (score 1):

Beside the performance improvements being mentioned in other answers here, I'd like to point out a very important distinction of choosing between WCF and Web API:

1. You can get the same from both of them, but **WebAPI** is designed to work with HTTP (and mainly with **JSON**) and **WCF** needs more configuration to be HTTP (**SOAP** as default messaging).
2. **WCF** have support for many sort of transportation protocols such as message queuing, one way messaging or duplex, TCP, HTTP of course and more.
3. **WCF** can be configured in such a way that when 1 of the above is available and is faster than the others, it can be used like TCP or even UDP (on later versions)...
4. Of course, every one of those channels needs configuration, which can be sometimes a pain in the neck.
5. The **WebAPI** was designed to work with the **HTTP**, so it supports request/response, headers, media formats (text, **JSON**, jpeg, XML...), URI, caching and more.
6. **SOAP** handling and transport is 'heavier' than **JSON**. Period. That's the main reason of preferring JSON over XML over the past 10 years or so.
7. By choosing Web API when your service can be exposed to a vast range of clients, mainly browsers, but also mobiles!
8. WebAPI is a light-weight framework which is good for smartphones having limited bandwidth.
9. As mentioned, clients has evolved to be robust frameworks, like **JQuery, Angular, Android** and more. All need fast data transfer from the service. Currently, **JSON** is the most simplest and fastest way of handling data between client and server and **WebAPI** is working seamlessly with it.

So before coding it is better to know what each framework do the best and choose accordingly.